# mongoDB find and update or insert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoDB and mongoose.

I have the following scheme:

```
{ "group" : 
    "items" : [ 
                {
                    "name": "aaa",
                    "value": "aaa_value",
                    "description": "some_text"
                },
                {
                    "name": "bbb",
                    "value": "bbb_value"
                    "description": "some_text2"
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "ccc",
                    "value": "ccc_value"
                    "description": "some_text3"
                },  
        ]
}
```

My function receives a name and a value.
If an item with this name is presented, I want to update the value according to the value parameter (and do not change the description).
If not, I want to add a new item to the array, with the parameter name and value, and a default description.

How can it be done?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upsert operation is not possible on embedded array. It has be to 2 step process.

Either you first (try to) remove record and then push it. Or update the record first, and if that fails, then insert it.

First approach: (first delete it)

```
db.collection.update(
  { _id : ObjectId("xyz")},
  { $pull: {"items.name": "aaa"}}
)
```

then, insert it:

```
db.collection.update(
  { _id : ObjectId("xyz")},
  { $push: {"items": {
         name : "ddd",
         value: "new value",
         description: "new description"
  }}
)
```

Second Approach: (first update it)

```
var result = db.collection.update(
{
   _id : ObjectId("xyz"),
   "items.name": "aaa")
},
{
   $set: {"items.$.name": {name: "new name"}}
}
);
```

And then, if nothing updates, then insert it.

```
if(!result.nMatched)
{
db.collection.update(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("xyz"),
        "items.name": {$ne: ObjectId("xyz"}}
    },
    {
        $push: {
            items: {
                name: "new name",
                value: "new value",
                description: "new description"
            }
        }
    }
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since it's a two-op process, should I worry some how about synchronization?